# How to add a description to tqdm pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, tqdm

I would like to put a small description in front of (or after, does not really matter) the tqdm pandas progress bars, somthing like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.auto import tqdm; tqdm.pandas()

a = pd.Series(np.arange(100))

squares = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**2) #this one works
cubes = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**3) #this one works

squares = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**2, desc = 'Computing squares...') #this one doesn't work
cubes = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**3, desc = 'Computing cubes...') #this one doesn't work
```

So, how can I add a description to progress bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm.auto import tqdm

a = pd.Series(np.arange(100))

tqdm.pandas(desc='Computing squares')
squares = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**2)

tqdm.pandas(desc='Computing cubes')
cubes = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**3)
```

**Output**:

```
Computing squares: 100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:00<00:00, 37766.11it/s]
Computing cubes: 100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:00<00:00, 30211.80it/s]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work but you will get a warning:

```
squares = a.progress_map(lambda x: x**2,print('Computing squares...') )
```